# Doubly Link List Insert in Order

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been trying to create a doubly link list in which each inserted value will be sorted in ascending order. I have tried writing some code but the code seems to always crash.

Here is what i got:

```
void DoublyList::insertInOrder(int insertItem)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->setData(insertItem);

    if (first == NULL)
        first->setData(insertItem);
    else
    {
        if (temp->getData() <= first->getData())
        {
            temp->setNextLink(first);
            first->setPreviousLink(temp);
            first = temp;
        }
        Node *curr = first;
        while (curr->getNextLink() != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->getData() <= curr->getData())
            {
                curr->getPreviousLink()->setNextLink(temp);
                temp->setPreviousLink(curr->getPreviousLink());
                temp->setNextLink(curr);
                curr->setPreviousLink(temp);
            }
            curr->setNextLink(temp);
            temp->setPreviousLink(curr);
        }
    }
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: You tried A, expected B, but got C.  Explain A, B, and C.

Comment: @horns It builds, but when i run it I get "Unhandled exception at 0x0097697B in Project.exe"

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have

```
if (first == NULL)
        first->setData(insertItem);
```

If `first` is `NULL`, de-referencing it or calling any of its member functions will cause you program to crash (and generate a core-dump)

Comment: I have tried changing `first->setData(insertItem);` to `first = temp` but still crash.

Comment: run `gdb <path to binary> <path to core dump file>` then when it stops running type `bt` and past the results in your answer